# To add column name in files using awk

Tags: unix, awk, scripting

This is my command:

```
awk \
  -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" \
  -F"," \
  'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{ gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' \
  Test_01012020.CSV
```

I manage to get this but I want included my **column name**

Comment: What do you mean by your column name? What the input looks like? What output would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you imply that you want to include the headers for the file. If this is so, you can do that by using sed command.  You can add this command at the end of your command using a pipe separator.

```
sed '1i header_value_1,header_value2,.....'
```

and so on as many headers you want.